# How parse object in HttpServletResponse?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets, jdo

I have a problem when I try to encode object in http response. I do not know how to do it. I will have use the header?

```
public class Download extends HttpServlet{


    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws IOException{


        PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();

        String method = req.getParameter("method");

        if(method.equals("view")){
            Query query = pm.newQuery(Article.class);
            List<Article> articles=null;

            try {
                articles=(List<Article>) query.execute();
                }
                finally {
                query.closeAll();
                }
                Article article= art.get(0);
                res.setContentType("application/octet-stream");//??
                //problem here



        }
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a setHeader() method on the HttpServletResponse class.  For example, you can set the content type using the following statement:

```
response.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html");
```

Here is a link with a good tutorial on the topic: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-servlets/httpresponse.html

Here is the JavaDoc on the class if you need more parameters:

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html